# nginx ingress controller with Lets Encrypt SSL

Tags: devops, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress

While trying to create an Nginx ingress controller with Lets Encrypt, I am getting error like below:

> Error during sync: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer default-ingress-XXXX-XXX--97c2xxxxxxf823a0 does not exist: Cert creation failures - k8s-ssl-6c974xxxxxxxx0f0-e3bxxxxxx1c14--97c2xxxxxx3a0 Error:googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.certificate': ''. A certificate must be specified for SSL certificate creation., invalid

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - api.domain.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  rules:
    - host: api.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: 80
```

I have already installed ingress nginx-ingress controller via helm charts.

Comment: it looks like https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1343 . Have you been checking it?

Comment: @Nick thanks. Issue resolved. Forgot to mention kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" in Ingress configuration.

Comment: glad to hear that. Would you mind to post that as an answer and mark it as accepted one, so another person can see a solution as well?